# My code can pass through 3 usage but I don't know why I can't pass the other

Tags: go

The question is:
Little Code has recently been playing Ice Adventure, an n-line m-column grid game. There are some impassable obstacles on some of the grids, and the rest of the grids are smooth ice.

The player is in it,ally on one of the non-obstacle grids, and remains stationary. Then he will following the character to move up and down, left and right; when he holds the characters move in one direction, the character will be on the ice surface to slide. The nature have for you here top moving until the next grid in the direction the character is moving is an obstacle or beyond the map boundary, then the surface will continue to wait for the next action of the little yard brother.

Now given the positions of all the obstacles in the map, the initial position of Little Yard and the sequence of Little Yard's actions, please find the position where Little Yard finally stays.

And here is my code

```
package main

import "fmt"
func yi(x,y int, s byte, a [][]int) (x1,y1 int){
    switch(s){
        
        case 'L':
            for{
                if y==0 || a[x][y-1]==1{
                    return x,y
                }
                y--

            }
        case 'R':
            for{
                if y==4 || a[x][y+1]==1{
                    return x,y
                }
                y++

            }
        case 'U':
            for{
                if x==0 || a[x-1][y]==1{
                    return x,y
                }
                x--

            }
        case 'D':
            for{
                if x==4 || a[x+1][y]==1{
                    return x,y
                }
                x++

            }

            
    }
    return x1,y1
}
func main() {

    var x,y,xc,yc,count int
    fmt.Scanf("%d %d",&x,&y)
    fmt.Scanf("%d %d",&xc,&yc)
    fmt.Scanf("%d",&count)
    // s:= make([]int,1,1)
    i:=count
        
    // }
    arr := make([][]int, x)
 for i := 0; i < x; i++ {
  arr[i] = make([]int, y)
 }
    // var arr [6][6]int
    for j:=0;j<i;j++{   
        var xt,yt int
        fmt.Scanf("%d %d",&xt,&yt)
        arr [xt-1][yt-1]=1
    }
    // for i:=0;i<x;i++{
    //     for j:=0;j<y;j++{
    //         fmt.Print(arr[i][j]," ")
    //     }
    //     fmt.Println()
    // }

    var kong string
    fmt.Scanf("%s",&kong)
    xf,yf:=xc-1,yc-1
    // xf,yf=yi(xf,yf,'R',arr)
    // fmt.Println(string(kong[7]))
    for i:=0; i<8; i++{
        xf,yf=yi(xf,yf,kong[i],arr)
        // fmt.Println(xf,yf)
        // func yi(x,y int, i int, s string, a *[5][5]int) (x1,y1 int){

    } 
    fmt.Println(xf+1,yf+1)

}
```

I try to figure it out, but I need to find out where the problem is. Can you help me to figure it out(I don't know about the usage the professor used)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understand you correctly, I think maybe your code forget to use the variety. In the code, you wrote:

```
for i:=0; i<8; i++{
        xf,yf=yi(xf,yf,kong[i],arr)
        // fmt.Println(xf,yf)
        // func yi(x,y int, i int, s string, a *[5][5]int) (x1,y1 int){

    }
```

I think 8 is a subjective `const` and I think it should be changed.
Here is my solution, hope to help you:

```
package main

import "fmt"
func yi(x,y int, s byte, a [][]int) (x1,y1 int){
    switch(s){
        
        case 'L':
            for{
                if y==0 || a[x][y-1]==1{
                    return x,y
                }
                y--

            }
        case 'R':
            for{
                if y==4 || a[x][y+1]==1{
                    return x,y
                }
                y++

            }
        case 'U':
            for{
                if x==0 || a[x-1][y]==1{
                    return x,y
                }
                x--

            }
        case 'D':
            for{
                if x==4 || a[x+1][y]==1{
                    return x,y
                }
                x++

            }

            
    }
    return x1,y1
}
func main() {

    var x,y,xc,yc,count int
    fmt.Scanf("%d %d",&x,&y)
    fmt.Scanf("%d %d",&xc,&yc)
    fmt.Scanf("%d",&count)
    // s:= make([]int,1,1)
    i:=count
        
    // }
    arr := make([][]int, x)
 for i := 0; i < x; i++ {
  arr[i] = make([]int, y)
 }
    // var arr [6][6]int
    for j:=0;j<i;j++{   
        var xt,yt int
        fmt.Scanf("%d %d",&xt,&yt)
        arr [xt-1][yt-1]=1
    }
    // for i:=0;i<x;i++{
    //     for j:=0;j<y;j++{
    //         fmt.Print(arr[i][j]," ")
    //     }
    //     fmt.Println()
    // }

    var kong string
    fmt.Scanf("%s",&kong)
    xf,yf:=xc-1,yc-1
    // xf,yf=yi(xf,yf,'R',arr)
    // fmt.Println(string(kong[7]))
    for i:=0; i<count; i++{
        xf,yf=yi(xf,yf,kong[i],arr)
        // fmt.Println(xf,yf)
        // func yi(x,y int, i int, s string, a *[5][5]int) (x1,y1 int){

    } 
    fmt.Println(xf+1,yf+1)

}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, althouth it's not 'count' but you figure out my question

Comment: You need to add some commit next time